# How to sum across columns automatically?

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

Would like your help to solve the problem as file attached.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E3KTOYHuYIJy9uQKsvlXwbCpwL6cU1IHAQ-Yirb-AfQ/edit#gid=0

I would like each column to sum automatically (using ArrayFormula) when there is new name added and amount added in each row of the same column.

Comment: That is a Google sheet not Excel.  Which of the two are you using?  The formula may be different.  If it is Google sheets then this belongs on WebApps.Stackexchange.com.  If it is Excel then post the data in a mark down text table in the question that shows the data and the expected results.

Comment: Using `Google Sheets` one could use `=ARRAYFORMULA(BYCOL(B7:E13,LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))+B4:E4)` and with `Excel` --> just remove the `ARRAYFORMULA()`

Comment: And what have you tried so far? This is not a free scripting site. We help those who make efforts to help themselves.